# Checking if cell is populated

Tags: excel, vba

I have an HTML report that can be opened in Excel.  I have written macros to format this report so it is sortable and can have filters applied.

I am trying to grab text between slashes.  The report size, how many rows, is unknown.

Column A is blank.  Column B will contain the full path name.  IF column B is populated, column C should have the text between the slashes.

For example, column B contains R:\testdocuments\test.html. I want column C to contain testdocuments.

Code I have for column C:

```
Range("C9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=MID(RC[-1], FIND(""\"",RC[-1])+1, FIND(""\"",RC[-1], FIND(""\"",RC[-1])+1)-FIND(""\"",RC[-1])-1)"
Range("C9").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C9:C65000"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("C9:C20000").Select
```

This is not effective because it takes forever to sort/filter anything.

How can I check if column B is populated and if it is, to populate C with the text between slashes for the ability to filter by directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, a few general tips:

1. When writing macros, you can work with Ranges without selecting them.
2. Use the following code at the beginning of your macro to prevent the application from animating (which slows it down): `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

   **Edit:** Make sure and set it back to 'True' after you're done.
3. Instead of `Range("C9:C65000")`, you can actually let Excel find the last row for you using `Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row`.

So, the macro might look something like this:

```
Sub FillFormulas()
    Dim row As Integer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    row = Range("B9").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).row
    Range("C9").Formula = "=MID(B9, FIND(""\"",B9)+1, FIND(""\"",B9, FIND(""\"",B9)+1)-FIND(""\"",B9)-1)"
    Range(Range("C9"), Range("C" & row)).FillDown
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lance, I'm sure it's not a bad idea to set Application.ScreenUpdating back to True, but I've written tons of macros where I haven't and have never noticed any ill effects.

Comment: @DanThMan, That's interesting, I've never tried not doing it, maybe it auto-resets after code completion.